# None type has no attribute index

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
nums= [1,2,2,3]

def removnt(nums):
    for n in nums:
        i = nums.index(n)
        if nums[i]==nums[i+1]:
            nums = nums.remove(n)

removnt(nums)
```

## Assume proper indent at all places.

The error that I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "source_file.py", line 20, in <module>
    removnt(nums)
  File "source_file.py", line 9, in removnt
    i = nums.index(n)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

How can I fix this attribute error?

Comment: `nums.remove(n)` modifies in-place, it does not return anything.

Comment: Removing items from a list while iterating over it won't work the way you want it to work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that should do what you want:

```
nums= [1,2,2,3]

def removnt(nums):
    i = 0
    while i < len(nums) - 1:
        if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
            del nums[i]
        else:
            i += 1

removnt(nums)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you just explain the cause of the error or what is the reason for throwing this error?